# Regular expression in django urls for self referenced module

Tags: regex, django, django-urls

What regular expression i have to write in my django urls to **simulate**, in the url, the path to a file? Where there are "directories", "subdirectories" and "files" and each object of those have a "slug" at the model.

I already have done this:

model.py

```
class Directory(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=100, unique=True,)
    subdirectory = models.ForeignKey('self', null=True, blank=True)

class File(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=100, unique=True,)
    directory = models.ForeignKey(Directory)
```

views.py

```
class DirectoryView(generic.DetailView):
    model = Directory
    template_name = 'appname/directory.html'


class FileView(generic.DetailView):
    model = File
    template_name = 'appname/file.html'
```

appname/urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^(?P<slug>[-\w]+)/$',
        views.DirectoryView.as_view(), name='directory'),
    url(r'^(?P<slug1>[-\w]+)/(?P<slug>[-\w]+)/$',
        views.FileView.as_view(), name='file'),
]
```

The result url for the "file1.txt" is:

- folder1
- folder2

  - subfolder1

    - file1.txt

http:/mydomain.com/appname/subfolder1/file1txt

but i need it to be:

http:/mydomain.com/appname/**folder2**/subfolder1/file1txt

Thanks,

Iván

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So i finally found the answer in this django snippet:

https://djangosnippets.org/snippets/362/

This is what i got at the end:

**models.py**

```
class Directory(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=100, unique=True,)
    parent = models.ForeignKey('self', null=True, blank=True)

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        url = "/%s/" % self.slug
        cwd = self
        while cwd.parent:
            url = "/%s%s" % (cwd.parent.slug, url)
            cwd = cwd.parent
        return url

class File(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=100, unique=True,)
    directory = models.ForeignKey(Directory)
```

**views.py**

```
from django.http import Http404
from django.shortcuts import render, get_object_or_404
from .models import Archive, Directory, File

def directories(request, full_slug):
    slugs = full_slug.split('/')
    cwd_slug = slugs[-1]
    directory = get_object_or_404(Directory, slug=cwd_slug)
    if not directory.get_absolute_url().strip('/') == full_slug:
        raise Http404
    # if you reach this line, you've found the directory

    context = {'directory': directory}
    template = 'appname/directory.html'
    return render(request, template, context)


def files(request, full_slug, file_slug):
    slugs = full_slug.split('/')
    cwd_slug = slugs[-1]
    directory = get_object_or_404(Directory, slug=cwd_slug)
    if not directory.get_absolute_url().strip('/') == full_slug:
        raise Http404
    files = get_object_or_404(File, name=file_slug)
    # if you reach this line, you've found the file

    context = {'archive': archive_slug, 'directory': full_slug, 'file': files}
    template = 'getdocs/file.html'
    return render(request, template, context)
```

**appname/urls.py**

```
from django.conf.urls import url, include
from . import views

file_patterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.directories, name='directory'),
    url(r'^(?P<file_slug>(.*)[.]{1}[-\w]{3})$', views.files, name='file'),
]

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^(?P<full_slug>(.*))/', include(file_patterns)),
]
```

I hope this helps others.

Comment: This matches to http:/mydomain.com/appname/folder1/subfolder1/file1.txt